# Sideloaded app is not listed in Assigned Access

Tags: windows, kiosk-mode

I tried to set up assigned access in my windows 10 as given below. But I couldn't find my sideloaded UWP app in:

```
Settings > Accounts > Family & other people > set up assigned access
> choose user for assigned access > choose user for assigned access
```

*windows.aboveLockScreen* extension is in manifest file as given.

```
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.lockScreenCall" />
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.aboveLockScreen" />
</Extensions>
```

I tried to achieve the task via powershell.

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId com.abi_08gsnwnf4ggb0!App -UserName kiosk_user
```

But got error.

```
New-CimInstance : One or more parameter values passed to the method were invalid.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\AssignedAccess\AssignedAccess.psm1:310 char:13
+             New-CimInstance -ClassName WEDL_AssignedAccess -Property  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (WEDL_AssignedAccess:CimInstance) [New-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 4,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimInstanceCommand
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took one week to me to figure it out my mistake. I had tried many other approaches. I am listing the solution here for those who gets stuck by the same issue since `Set-AssignedAccess` is not giving proper error.

The app was installed in admin account not in the *kiosk_user* account!!
The AUMID I used was from admin account not from kisok user acccount!!

**Make sure the app is installed in the kiosk user account and the AUMID is from the kiosk user account!**